# Delay in getting badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I recently was awarded the Enlightened badge for the first time, and I'm proud to say it was for an extremely difficult question with an extremely [insightful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/209925/8671).  Of course, this implies I also was awarded a Nice Answer badge, though I had one of those before.  However, I was awarded the Nice Answer badge maybe 30 minutes before the Enlightened badge.  I am just curious how this works?  Is it that the voting systems are separate and take longer to update or something?  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: A related question at meta.SO: [How long until a bronze tag badge shows up?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72816/how-long-until-a-bronze-tag-badge-shows-up)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some jobs running at specific intervals handing out the badges. The badges that are more expensive to calculate are checked less often than the simple badges.

So there can always be a delay between fulfilling the badge criteria and the time you actually get awarded the badge.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's all I was wondering about!

Comment: @daniel You have voted more than 600 times, but the electorate badge is for voting 600 times **on questions**.