# Civic Duty silver badge: 301-th vote needed?

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delay in getting badges](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6327/delay-in-getting-badges)

My function of $\text{Votes}_\text{total}=V(t)$ has finally intersected $V(t)=300$ today. However when I had casted exactly $300$ votes, I didn't get the badge according to its description:

> Voted $300$ or more times.

**I casted the $301$-th vote, then came the very silver badge *immediately.***

Is it merely a lag, or the $301$-th vote is really needed to gain the badge? Do we need to reword the description? I think that we MSE people should be mathematically precise.

Comment: Wasn't that just another instance of the usual [Delay in getting badges](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6327/delay-in-getting-badges)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. It was a coincidence. Vote to close.